# function is timing out when http-triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions, jimp

**What am I doing wrong? Why is the function timing out?**

I have a blob triggered function which works totally fine:

```
const Jimp = require("jimp");

module.exports = function(context, myBlob) {
  const correlation = context.bindings.inputBlob.correlation;
  const inputImage = context.bindings.inputBlob.image;
  const imageName = context.bindings.inputBlob.imageName;

  context.log(
    correlation + "Attempting to convert this image to a tiff: " + imageName
  ); 
  Jimp.read(Buffer.from(inputImage, "base64"), function(err, image) {
    image.getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_TIFF, function(error, tiff) {
      const response = {
        myimage: tiff.toString("base64"),
        correlation: correlation
      };
      context.bindings.outputBlob = response
      context.log(
        correlation + "Successfully converted " + imageName + " to tiff."
      );
      context.done();
    });
  });
};
```

Here is the **function.json** file:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "images-in/{destination}/{name}",
      "connection": "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"
    },
    {
      "name": "inputBlob",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "images-in/{destination}/{name}",
      "connection": "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "{destination}/{name}.tiff",
      "connection": "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

**The way it works:**

1. drop a blob into a specific location
2. output blob will be generated
   by the function in another location (the whole process takes no longer than about 5 seconds).

I decided that I needed the function to be http-triggered, so I made the following changes:

```
const Jimp = require("jimp");

module.exports = function(context, req) {

  Jimp.read(Buffer.from(req.body, "base64"), function(err, image) {
    image.getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_TIFF, function(error, tiff) {
      const response = {
        myimage: tiff.toString("base64"),
        correlation: "yeeeeees"
      };


    });
      context.res = {
          body: response
      };
      context.done();
  });


};
```

**function.json**:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I am getting a **500**:

[image]

The telemetry is showing the following:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? Why is the function timing out?**

I've made the following update to the function:

```
const Jimp = require("jimp");

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    const text = Buffer.from(req.body, "base64").toString("utf-8");

    Jimp.read(text, function(err, image) {
    if (err) {
      context.res = {
        body: err
      };
      context.done();
    }

    image.getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_TIFF, function(error, tiff) {
      if (error) {
        context.res = {
          body: error
        };
        context.done();
      }
      const response = {
        myimage: tiff.toString("base64"),
        correlation: "yeeeeees"
      };
      context.res = {
        body: response
      };
      context.done();
    });
  });
};
```

This yielded the following nonsensical response:

```
{
  "errno": -4058,
  "code": "ENOENT",
  "syscall": "open",
  "path": "D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\$R\u0005������{\u001av��r��Ū�O�$z�ނ)",
  "methodName": "constructor"
}
```

Comment: You're second code has an invalid reference to `response` (out of scope) and you are calling `done` too soon. Should be placed in the inner callback (which is executed later). Possibly this is not the correct representation of your code?

Comment: thanks! i've attempted to use the code from the answer below, however, i'm still getting timeouts

Answer (score 2):

If you check your node.js logs in Azure, you would see an error like `response is not defined` because your scope where you defined response is different then where you used.

So basically you are not able to call context.done(); function and that is why your request throwing timeout exception.

Using async/await will help you to not have this kind of problems. Please check this code example to understand what could go wrong.

```
const Jimp = require("jimp");

module.exports = function(context, req) {

  Jimp.read(Buffer.from(req.body, "base64"), function(err, image) {

    if(err){
      context.res = {
          body: err
      };
      context.done();
    }

    image.getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_TIFF, function(error, tiff) {
      if(error){
        context.res = {
          body: error
        };
        context.done();
      }
      const response = {
        myimage: tiff.toString("base64"),
        correlation: "yeeeeees"
      };
      context.res = {
        body: response 
      };
      context.done();
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: after using your code, i am getting the following response `{
  "methodName": "constructor"
}`   very weird!

Comment: here's a screenshot of the logs https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1OVaUY1QNVVVcI8cmgE76MjPjwBAD7bqI

Comment: Have you tried to use same code on your local with same image sample? Maybe you can debug what's wrong about it on your local.